# MVC,  MVP patterns and  solutions with more than one project

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp

I'd like to know what is a common practice when working with MVC, MVP or any other pattern where we can organise a solution containing several projects.

For instance: For MVP I could have a view project, a presenter project and a model project with in a solution. And a similiar solution layout for MVC, where I can have several projects forming a solution. I believe this could also be the case for an MVVM solution, which could posibly contain several projects.

When working we these solutions, each project would generate a seperate dll. So for an solution organised in an MVP pattern, the presenter project would generate it's own .dll.

I'd like to know what is a common practice when working with this kind of layout with in a solution, where we have more than one project and avoid that somebody  could potentially  add a reference directly to , for instance, a generated presenter.dll or controller.dll and call methods, instatiate types defined in these .dlls.

I'd like to know:
1) Am I am using these  patterns correctly or am I completly wrong by organising my solutions containing several projects?

2) Should I have all my code with in one project and organise either controllers/presenters/models  in  folders so I would generate one .exe or .dll for each solution. The problem I see with this approach is , for an MVP layout, I would miss out on being able to have different views using my presenter project. (For instance a WebSite view, WebService view).

3) What is a common practice when using MVC/MVP  or any other pattern where we could organise  solutions containing several projects so I can control who is calling my code.

Answer (score 1):

On a previous MVP project, we organized like you mentioned, Views (in the web project), Models, Presenters, Interfaces, etc. For MVC you'll be better off following the default structure given by the studio, at least for views and controllers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question btw. I have worked with the ASP.NET MVC framework and using MVP with webforms, with the MVC Framework coming out tops. The following article provides insights about both patterns or the 1 pattern as MVP is more of a variant/derivative.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/06/16/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-mvc-and-mvp-but.aspx

1. If your application or business needs demand that your MVC/MVP parts be split into different project then that's the way to go. Your reuse of the controller definitely constitutes are reason for placing this within a different project.
2. Visual studio or indeed MSsbuild provides the ability to merge assemblies. This is not something that bears worrying about as in no way will this impact the performance of your application, but may on the other hand pose you development or sharing problems which will be more of a debt that having several assemblies.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx

3./ A common practice is to group the models and controllers into one assembly/project and have the views in a separate project. Since View Models are normally intertwined with the controller / presenter then any system that wishes to reuse the controller will normally require the view models.

A good indicator of whether you are using the pattern correct is to identify whether you are getting the benefits of the pattern.